# How can I redirect to a specific controller/action with similar routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, hyperlink, routes

My routes are redirecting to the same controller even when I specified different properties inside my routes.rb file.

These are my routes.

```
match ':clube_id' => 'clubes#show', :as => 'clean_cluble', via: [:get]
match ':project_id' => 'projects#show', :as => 'clean_project',via: [:get]
```

These are the links that I am using.

```
=link_to 'Project', :controller => "projects", :action => "show", :project_id=>'xxxxx'
=link_to 'Clube', :controller => "clubes", :action => "show", :id=>'cccc'
```

The link for projects works well, but the linl for clubes is redirecting to projects controller. that is the problem.

The URLs that I spect are:

```
http://host_name/project_name
http://host_name/clube_name
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify different properties, both routes look's identical for Rails. The `match` method expect any string(or id) in the `':clube_id'` or `':project_id'`, for example:

```
 host_name/soho_project or host_name/1
```

How is Rails can recognize for a which model it's related?  It can be a `Project` or `Club`. I suggest add something like the *anchor* to a `match` method.

```
match 'club/:clube_id' => 'clubes#show', :as => 'clean_cluble', via: [:get]
match 'project/:project_id' => 'projects#show', :as => 'clean_project',via: [:get]
```

and helpers:

```
= link_to 'Project', clean_project_path(:project_id=>'xxxxx')
= link_to 'Clube', clean_cluble_path(:clube_id=>'cccc')
```

<sub>Read more about routes from the Rails [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).</sub>